# How to block the page scrolling without affecting the style?

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar

I'd like to block the page scrolling but without change my page style (e.g. using *overflow: hidden;*).

I tried to use this:

```js
$('body').on('scroll mousewheel touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    return false
});
```

but but the scrolling didn't blocked and I received this console error:

```
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See <URL>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the right way to disable the scrolling:

```
function preventScroll(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
}

document.addEventListener('wheel', preventScroll, { passive: false })
```

In order to allow it again:

```
document.removeEventListener('wheel', preventScroll, { passive: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are.

```js
$('body').on('scroll mousewheel touchmove', function(e) {
  // Get the current page scroll position 
  let scrollTop =  
    window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
  let scrollLeft =  
    window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft, 

    // if any scroll is attempted, 
    // set this to the previous value 
    window.onscroll = function() { 
    window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop); 
  }; 
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: I receive this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollTop is not defined`

Comment: I think you forgot `let` in front of `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`. Furthermore, how can I undo the behavior?

Comment: function enableScroll() { 
            window.onscroll = function() {}; 
        }

Comment: That method has a strange behavior: I cannot scroll the page but I can. I mean, for a fraction of second I can see the scrolling effect, this didn't prevent upstream the scrolling like `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I couldn’t find another way